# cannot assign ip address from dhcp

Tags: ubuntu, pxe

I am trying to boot through PXE. 
DHCP and TFTP are raised and work, but in one moment when client requests iso from server I got this:

```
udhcp: sending discover
.....
udhcp: no lease, failing
could not assign ip address from dhcp
```

and connecting, written in every config file, through 10.0.0.1 cannot be established. I found in web some cases, similar to mine, but nothing has to do with PXE-boot.

Where can I detect this error?

Answer (score 2):

One option could be to sniff the traffic using wireshark or any similar tool. To see if there is any issues with the traffic between both comuputers.

It looks like the DHCP server is not assignint IP so your guess that it has nothing to do with PXE may be true